# How Can I Write A Program for File Synchronization Between Drives

Tags: java, synchronization, desktop

While working; there was a problem and my C drives can not be reachable anymore.Now I want to write a program to sychronize Desktop and D. Which way i should follow.

Additionally ;
 I tried to perform this without any program following way but failed.

```
subst D: c:\users\geek\desktop
```

creating a virtual driver and map it to desktop and D driver .

Thanks

Comment: is your c: drive defective or what do you wan to achieve? If it is not reachable then a program won't reach it either. Maybe a drive recovery solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Java, C# or any other platform

With Java you can follow this tutorial. Just watch the directory for changes then copy changed files to other drive.

[Watching a Directory for Changes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)

for C# you can use this class and apply same solution

[.NET FileSystemWatcher Class Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

or simply you can use some tool for synchronization

[FreeFileSync](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freefilesync/)

Good luck

Comment: If you don't include the actual code solutions in your answer then this answer will break as soon as the links expire